# CSS animation not working only on Safari latest version

Tags: css, animation, safari, css-animations

I am trying to find the compatibility issue with Safari to no avail in a CSS glitch text animation, all keyframes are on and the animation is specified with each property, i cut the middle keyframes to make it simpler:

```
.glitch {

   animation-name: glitch-skew;
 animation-duration: 1s;
 animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 animation-delay: 0s;
}
.glitch::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 3px;
  text-shadow: -3px 0 #ff00c1;
 animation-name: glitch-anim;
 animation-duration: 6s;
 animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 animation-delay: 0s;
}
.glitch::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: -3px;
  text-shadow: -3px 0 #00fff9, 3px 3px #ff00c1;
   animation-name: glitch-anim2;
 animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 animation-delay: 0s;
}


@keyframes glitch-anim {
  0% {
    clip: rect(79px, 9999px, 90px, 0);
    transform: skew(0.57deg);
  }
  5% {
    clip: rect(4px, 9999px, 59px, 0);
    transform: skew(0.73deg);
  }

  100% {
    clip: rect(40px, 9999px, 94px, 0);
    transform: skew(0.6deg);
  }
}
@keyframes glitch-anim2 {
  0% {
    clip: rect(96px, 9999px, 50px, 0);
    transform: skew(0.7deg);
  }
  5% {
    clip: rect(81px, 9999px, 66px, 0);
    transform: skew(0.38deg);
  }

  100% {
    clip: rect(96px, 9999px, 10px, 0);
    transform: skew(0.08deg);
  }
}
@keyframes glitch-skew {
  0% {
    transform: skew(0deg);
  }
  
  100% {
    transform: skew(0deg);
  }
}
```

Any ideas on what could be the issue here? Or maybe there is a way to hide this animation only on safari devices? I know its a long shot

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try using the `-webkit` prefix for the animation elements (such as `-webkit-animation-duration`, `-webkit-animation-name`, etc.), since safari is a webkit browser, targeting the css styles to its framework should have an impact.